# Проблема при реализации взаимодействия профилировщика утечек и программы

Tags: c++, отладка, утечка-памяти

Возникла необходимость написать профилировщик утечек памяти и времени работы программы. Для этого реализован был класс, хранящий время начала программы и дерево из адресов и размеров выделенных блоков.

Вопрос же заключается в том, как заставить этот класс работать, как надо. Помимо необходимости переопределить операторы `new`/`new[]`/`malloc`/`delete`/etc. есть необходимость наличии того, к чему можно обращаться из новых new/etc. В этом и состоит вопрос.

При попытке использовать `static` объект класса возникла проблема в многократном количестве объектов такого класса, если файл с профайлером был подключен в разных `.cpp` файлах; при использовании шаблона singleton возникает проблема в уничтожении объекта и в том, что этот объект создается не раньше первого выделения памяти, а не при старте алгоритма; использование `static` переменной для времени требует её инициализации, что невозможно сделать с помощью `gettimeofday` вне тела какой-либо функции и с множеством других проблем я столкнулся при попытке реализовать взаимодействие программы с моим профайлером.

Хотелось бы узнать, как можно реализовать необходимое мне взаимодействие и не столкнуться с множеством проблем при компиляции и при работе программы.

Comment: Использовать singleton? https://gist.github.com/pazdera/1098119

Comment: *"Возникла необходимость"* - вы в этом уверены? Существующие профилировщики памяти чем не угодили? *"при использовании шаблона singleton возникает проблема в уничтожении объекта и в том, что этот объект создается не раньше первого выделения памяти"* - вы явно что-то делаете неправильно, наверняка используете антипаттерн "meyers singleton"

Comment: Если использовать сингтон, то как заставить таймер быть проинициализированным в самом начале работы программы?

Comment: Грузить сингл первым, в нем таймер, таймер стартует в конструкторе. В чем сложность? Делаете пустой метод, например с именем .Init() - его и вызывайте в самом начале. `single::instance->Init()`

Comment: Когда я пытался обратиться к какой-либо функции вне тела другой функции, возникала ошибка при компиляции. Разве обращение к полю класса не должно вызывать вновь проблему?